# xmlhttprequest onlys gets to status 3

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a simple search form with a search box and a result box.

When I type a search word a request is created like: http://www.site.com/php_handler.php?s=hello
In the php script and a result is given back to the script this way:

```
<?php return $s; ?>
```

The problem is that my htmlrequest stops at readyState 3 it doesn't get to 4.

The javascript looks like this:

```
var xmlhttp = sajax_init_object();

function sajax_init_object() {
        var A;
        try {
            A=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                A=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (oc) {
                A=null;
            }
        }
        if(!A && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
            A = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (!A)
            sajax_debug("Could not create connection object.");
        return A;
    }
function getSearchItem()
  {
        gs=document.forms.mainform.resultsfield;
        var searchword=document.forms.mainform.searchform.value;
        if (searchword.length>=3)
        {
        setWaitCursor();
        clearResults();
        var uri = "http://site.com/ajax_handler.php?s="+searchword;
        console.log(uri);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", uri, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
        {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
          processResults(xmlhttp.responseText);
                removeWaitCursor();
        }else{
            console.log(xmlhttp.readyState);
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
      alert("please add at least 3 characters ."); 
    }    
  }
```

Can someone tell me why it stops at 3?

edit: here is also the php code:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

session_start();


//include main file
require_once($_SESSION["FILEROOT"] . "xsite/init.php");

//check if formulier is posted

$zoekterm = C_GPC::getGETVar("s");
$s="";

if ($zoekterm != "") {
    $query="SELECT number,name,city,zib,zip_annex FROM articles WHERE version='edit' AND (naam LIKE '%$school%' OR brinnummer='$school')  ORDER BY name";
    if ($rs=C_DB::fetchRecordSet($query)) {
        while ($row=C_DB::fetchRow($rs)) {
            if ($row["plaats"]!="") {
                $s.=$row["name"].", ".$row["city"]."|".$row["number"]."\n";
            } else {
                $s.=$row["name"].", ".$row["zip"].$row["zip_annex"]."|".$row["number"]."\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

return $s;


?>
```

edit:

**I missed a semicolon in my php script and now the ready state only gets to 2**

edit:

**The problem is even different. It gets to 4 but it doesn't show the result text.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1> Don't send Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0.  These don't do what you think they do, and they're entirely unnecessary.

2> Your AJAX results page needs to send a Content-Length or Connection: Close header.

3> Try adding a random to your request URL to ensure you're not looking at a stale cache entry.

Answer (score 0):

ReadyState 3 => Some data has been received

ReadyState 4 => All the data has been received

Maybe the XMLHTTPRequest object is still waiting for some data.

Are you sure your php script ends correctly ?

Is the content-length alright ?

Comment: when I do the query straight in the db i get 4 records on my search term ;-). 
How can I debug the php code in an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this you have two options, type the URL directly into the browser [since you are using a GET] and see what is happening.

OR

You can use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what is exactly happening with the XMLHttpRequest